# div's contents showing, but not the div "box"

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

On my wordpress built site, with a Responsive theme child theme, there is a div which contains widgets.
The widgets and their content are showing fine, but the "wrapping" div is not showing what I have styled via css.  If I use firebug, I can see that the div is appearing up at the same spot as another div "featured", but is obviously behind it.  Well, I need it to be below.

The site is http://thelawcompany.com.au.

The problem div is `<div id="widgets" class="home-widgets">`.  I want the background and top-border that I have declared in CSS to appear behind the widgets.  Also, there is a massive gap below the widgets that I can't seem to get rid of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It because the `#featured` element is floated.

A solution is to float the `widgets` also by adding the class `grid`

Demo: [Problem](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/uhM3q/), [Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/uhM3q/1/)

```
<div id="widgets" class="home-widgets grid">
```

Comment: Perfect!  any idea about the padding/margin below that div that I can't seem to find?

Comment: where is the padding/margin? I cann't find anything there